# Насколько сейчас актуально WinAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi

Изучаю разработку программ на C++ по книгам. Там для создания окон и многого другого используется библиотека WinAPI. Хотелось бы узнать на сколько актуально сейчас написание программ с использованием этой библиотеки и если она устарела то хотелось бы получить информацию о современном ее аналоге.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под словом «устарела»? Создана более двух лет назад?

Comment: @Arhad нет. Я имею в виду к примеру такую ситуацию: К примеру программа написана на Directx 7 и скомпилированная запускается на любом устройстве с установленным Dx любой версии выше 7. Но если написать теми же функциями программу на Dx 12 и попробовать ее скомпилировать то у вас ничего не выйдет. Я хочу узнать на сколько актуальна сейчас данная библиотека и не устарели ли ее методы.

Comment: Отвечу на комментарий тремя пунктами, чтобы не мешать всё в кучу. 1. `... данная библиотека...` — WinAPI - это не какая-то одна библиотека, а все dll-файлы в `C:\Windows\System32`; каждая из библиотек даёт доступ к какой-то одной подсистеме. 2. `Я хочу узнать на сколько актуальна сейчас данная библиотека` — ничего актуальнее быть не может, т. к. это единственный способ взаимодействия с Windows, и потому в нём отражаются все фишки каждой новой версии ОС, вплоть до сервис-паков.

Comment: 3. `... и не устарели ли ее методы` — за обратной совместимостью в Microsoft следят так жёстко, что WinAPI до сих пор вынужден тащить за собой древние костыли и хаки, когда-либо использованные программистами в обход документации.

Comment: Вопрос построен на бессмысленной посылке. WinAPI - это WInAPI, а не "библиотека". Если вы пишете программы под Windows, то пишете вы их именно через WinAPI. Никаких других вариантов нет по определению. Любые другие библиотеки будут лишь посредниками между вами и WinAPI.

Comment: Всех благодарю за ответы. Я узнал нужную информацию всем по лайку. Вопрос можно закрыть.

Comment: Если брать отдельно WinAPI - то он не устареет, пока существует Windows. Если брать вкупе с _современным_ C++ - то можно практически полностью отказаться от WinAPI, т. к. в C++ есть всё необходимые библиотеки/фунции, заменяющие WinAPI. Причём, код при этом получается кроссплатформенным, а не прибитым намертво к одной оси.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, вот это поворот! Вообще-то такие мощные заявления стоило бы хоть минимально подтверждать. Ну продемонстрируйте, к примеру, как стандартной библиотекой C++ сделать то же, что делает простейшая функция WinAPI `MessageBox`. :) Вы случаем C++ с C# не попутали?

Comment: @freim - вы про кроссплатформенность не заметили? Например, для работы с файлами можно использовать функции WinAPI OpenFile и т. п. А можно использовать функции C++ <fstream>. Используя последние, мы получаем кроссплатформенный код. В стандартных библиотеках C++ нет функций для создания GUI, поэтому, естественно, нет замены MessageBox. PS: в C# тоже нет функций/методов для работы с GUI (они есть во фреймворке).

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, WinAPI сильно шире файловых функций (которые в STL, кстати, весьма убогие), так что фразы вроде "_можно практически полностью отказаться от WinAPI, т. к. в C++ есть всё необходимые библиотеки/фунции, заменяющие WinAPI_" к реальности никакого отношения не имеют. Тем более даже для консольных программ - реальных программ, а не студенческих заданий - возможностей стандартной ибилиотеки обычно не хватает. Сторонние библиотеки вроде Qt или wxWidgets задачу решают, но даже там часто приходится выносить под условную компиляцию какие-то системнозависимые кусочки.